# Worklight 6.2 JSONStore issues on iOS

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

Since my update to WL6.2 i'm having issues with the JSONStore on iOS (7.1.1). There is a lot of unexpected behavior in my application. I have created a test app to indicate some of my issues. Just create a new WL project and replace the main.js file and add some buttons to the index.html.

index.html:

```
<button id="destroyJSONStore">Destroy JSON Store</button>
<button id="search">Search</button>
<button id="load">Load</button>
```

main.js:

```
function wlCommonInit(){
    document.getElementById("destroyJSONStore").onclick=function(){
        WL.JSONStore.destroy()
        .then(function() {
            alert("JSON Store Destroyed");
        });
    };

    document.getElementById("search").onclick=function(){
        var query = {UserID: 1};
        WL.JSONStore.get("Users").find(query)
        .then(function(res) {
            alert("Number of users found with ID 1: " + res.length);
        })

        .fail(function(errorObject) {
            alert("Error loading user: " + userId + "\n" + errorObject.msg);
        });
    };

    document.getElementById("load").onclick=function(){
        var data = [{UserID: 1, Login: 'hvb'}];
        var addOptions = {markDirty: true};

        WL.JSONStore.get("Users").add(data, addOptions)
        .then(function(added) {
            alert("User successfully added; " + added);
        })
        .fail(function (errorObject) {
            alert(errorObject.toString());
        });
    };

    var collections = {
        Persons : {
            searchFields : {name: 'string', age: 'integer'}
        }
    };

    var collections2 = {
        Users : {
            searchFields: { UserID: 'integer', Login: 'string'}
        }
    };

    var options = {
      username : 'jos',
      password : 'jos',
      localKeyGen : true
    };

    WL.JSONStore.init(collections, options)
    .then(function () {
        WL.Logger.debug("init persons ok");
    })
    .fail(function (errorObject) {
        alert(errorObject.toString());
    });

    WL.JSONStore.init(collections2, options)
    .then(function () {
        WL.Logger.debug("init Users ok");
    })
    .fail(function (errorObject) {
        alert(errorObject.toString());
    });           
}
```

The first time the app loads all is working fine, if you click load a new document is added in the store, if you click search the number of documents in the store is shown. However, when I start playing around with the app things go wrong. Close and open the app a couple of times and add new documents. After a while you'll notice the search keeps returning the same number of documents (regardless of how many times you click add).

You'll also notice that once you destroy the json store and reopen your application, you get a JSON_STORE_DATA_PROTECTION_KEY_FAILURE. You'll have to restart the application a second time to get rid of it.

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?
I'll admit that initializing the JSONSstore in two times may seem a bit odd. But this is because our application is build with different modules, and regarding of the configuration different modules are loaded. According to the documentation this shouldn't cause any problems:

> It is possible to initialize multiple times with different collections. New collections are initialized without affecting collections that are already initialized.

By the way: the app works as expected on Android and on the mobile browser simulator.

Comment: I don't know if this is what is causing your problem, but in your code, you should do the second init in the then() callback after the first init; otherwise, since JSONStore is an asynchronous API, it may cause weird behavior. You can actually simplify this and initialize both collections at the same time; just pass both collection objects in an array to init (that is, init([collections, collections2], options)) and it should work and make it simpler for you.

Comment: Daniel, your remark makes sense and I was already convinced this would solve my problem. I have modified my code and now the second JSONStore only gets initialized after the init of the first one is done. But the issue still remains. I know I could also do the init of both collections in one go, and this would probably solve my problem.  But as explained earlier, I'd rather keep the initialization seperated for different modules.

Comment: Daniel, I've tested your work-around and indeed, if I initialize the collections in one go, both issues are resolved. But this is just a work around, It should also work if I initialize the collections in two times.

Comment: Ok, let me investigate and see if I can reproduce the issue.

Comment: Daniel, there is a problem with my promises, you were right. The problem is due to both init statements being executed at the same time. When I add a timeout between the init statements, the issues are gone. I'll update my question and add an answer. Thanks for your support.

Comment: Ok, no problem! Please mark your own answer as the correct one so that this question does not appear unanswered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by Daniel, the problem is both init methods are being executed at the same time. This causes weird behavior. The solution is to call the second init after the first one is finished. Here is an example of how this can be done.

```
WL.JSONStore.init(collections, options)
.then(function () {
    WL.Logger.debug("init persons ok");
})
.then(function() {
    WL.JSONStore.init(collections2, options)
   .then(function () {
       WL.Logger.debug("init Users ok");
   })
   .fail(function (errorObject) {
       alert(errorObject.toString());
   });
})
.fail(function (errorObject) {
    alert(errorObject.toString());
});
```

Comment: It seems that the first .then() should not be there; the promise should be resolved with the second then I think, so I thought it might have just been a typo.

Answer (score 1):

I think I know what the problem is; you are displaying an alert after the destroy() call, and thinking that seeing the alert means that the destroy is done, but this is not true; destroy() is also an asynchronous API call, so like init, you have to use promises/callbacks to do the alert. For example:

```
WL.JSONStore.destroy()
.then(function(){
     alert('Destroy is done!');
});
```

Comment: This is indeed a mistake I made, but I don't think it's related to my problem. In my opinion the only impact is that the alert is shown a few moments too soon.

Comment: I have updated my question with your comment, but the JSON_STORE_DATA_PROTECTION_KEY_FAILURE exception still remains.